# MDbootstrap change border color of input focus

Tags: mdbootstrap

How can I change the input focus color in mdbootstrap5? The default color is blue and I want to change it to green. I'm not really an expert in customizing anything in bootstrap.

I tried changing colors in a custom CSS but still doesn't work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.